# How to install tightVNC on SUSE 12 SP2

Tags: suse, tightvnc

I am trying to install tightvnc on (throw putty):

SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP2  (x86_64) - Kernel \r (\l)

but getting this error:
[DevelRepo|http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/tools:/scm/SLE_11_SP2] Valid metadata not found at specified URL
Warning: Skipping repository 'DevelRepo' because of the above error.
Some of the repositories have not been refreshed because of an error.
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'tightvncserver' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'tightvncserver' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

any help with this?

Comment: Can't you use `tigervnc` instead?

Comment: suppose that tigervnc will be OK for me, how can I install it?
I tried same way like tightvnc but has the same error

Comment: I cant find both of them for SUSE 12 SP2 at:
https://software.opensuse.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&baseproject=ALL&q=tightvnc
does it mean its not available for those versions? any other site can contain the install?

Comment: What steps do you take to install the packages? How is your package manager configured?

Comment: I did:   yast2 -i tightvnc